# Texting contacts within an app

Tags: ios, sms

I've developed an app that allows the user to text contacts that they add in the app.  The problem I'm having is it seems that if the user already exists in the person's native iOS address book, the text will send no problem.  But if the contact exists only within the app, the text will not go through.  Has anyone else experienced something like this before?

EDIT: Code below

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
     controller.body = @"";
     controller.recipients = arrayContactMobileStrings;
     controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
     [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller   didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Message not sent", @"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Error sending message", @"")
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") otherButtonTitles: nil];
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            [alert show];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            [alert show];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Unrelated note: I would +1 your user name if I could.

Comment: @AyanSengupta Please see code above